# How to stand different dataframes side by side iteratively generated in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I have a code through which I am generating different DataFrames and appending them one over the other.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()


           ...
                           new_col = pd.read_parquet(filepath)
                           aux = pd.concat([aux, new_col])
               aux['measure'] = sn
               df = df.append(aux)
```

The code works fine, but I need them side by side. `df` is a empty dataframe in which I am appending all `aux` which contain all the data. Therefore, apparently, concat neither join or merge don't work since I cannot concat `df` and `aux`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to concatenate them, just make as you have done on the above line. However, concatenate them specifying the `axis=1` and the `join='outer'`. Nonetheless, you have to reset the index before because when concatenating it takes into account the index.

```
aux.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
df = pd.concat([df, aux], axis=1, join='outer')
```

Answer (score 0):

Side by side ?

```py
pd.concat(list_of_df, axis=1)
```

This should be good

Comment: TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'str'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid

Comment: You will have to show more of your code then. If your data are `private` create an example that we can easily copy past and run so we know exactly what we are talking about

Comment: could see my example? Thanks